# I need stop slideUp in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mouseover, slidedown, slideup

i write this code , it make a slideUp for me 
now I need when mouse over stop slide up 
regard

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ticker_02').mouseover(function() {
  //I NEED THIS CODE
    })

});

function tick2(){
    $('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker_02')).slideDown(); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 2000);
```

Comment: U want it to slide down mouse over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `stop()` method:

```
$('#ticker_02').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true);
})
```

Comment: hi, if you slide the `li:first` try it by changing the selector `$('#ticker_02 li').mouseover(...)`

Comment: Thank I solve this . my problem setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 2000); . stop worked but this start again .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function tick2(){
  $('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp(
    function () {
      $(this).appendTo($('#ticker_02')).slideDown();
    }
  );
}

d=setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 5000);

function stop1(){
  clearInterval(d);
}
function start1(){
  d=setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ticker_02" class="ticker" onmouseover="stop1()" onmouseout="start1()" >
  <li>element1</li>
  <li>element2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<ul id="ticker_02" class="ticker" onmouseover="stop1()" onmouseout="start1()">

<script>
var d
function tick2(){
    $('#ticker_02 li:first').slideUp( function () {    
        $(this).appendTo($('#ticker_02')).slideDown(); });
}
d=setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 2000);


function stop1(){
    clearInterval(d);
}

function start1(){
    setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, 2000);
}
</script>
```